# Cant click on button by css_selector in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have navigated to a (https://gmet.edupage.org/) webpage, logged in and got to the final step to complete my code, which is to click a next day arrow which cycles through the days of a calendar. Thing is while I have done this many times before the program still returns an error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"next.fa.fa-angle-right"}`

I wonder why cant it get the element when the source webpage code looks like this:

```
<span class="next fa fa-angle-right" data-smer="1" style="display:inline-block"></span>
```

My code looks like this:

```
next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_x('.next.fa.fa-angle-right')

next_page_button.click()
```

Any ideas on why this migh not work?

Comment: Have you run a curl command to see what the source code looks like without javascript? My guess would be that element only exists when javascript is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was pretty simple I just had to add a time.sleep command so that the page has time to load.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='next fa fa-angle-right']")

next_page_button.click()
```